# Simultaneously printing x number of times - Python

Tags: python, list, printing, append

I've been given a task to write a program that prints 'y' and 'n' a specified number of times. We have to use the starting code provided;

```
def my_string(size):
    #Code here...
    return out_string

print(my_string(3))  #Would print 'yny'
print(my_string(8))  #Would print 'ynynynyn'
```

But I have no idea where to start.

I've thought of looping though adding to a running total, and until that number is met then it will create a list of characters which would then be printed, however this seemed to be a problem because I was not able to figure out how to get the wanted length of the string.. :-L

```
def my_string(size):
    length = size
    times = 0
    current_print = [ ] 
    while times != length:
        current_print.append("y")
        times = times + 1
        current_print.append("n")
        times = times + 1

    return out_string
```

I kind of got lost after this point.
Any guidance with this task would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python you can simply do

```
def my_string(size):
    out_string = ('yn' * size)[:size]
    return out_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def my_string(size):
    times = 0
    current_print = ""
    while times < length:
        current_print += ("y", "n")[times % 2]
```

You could also use list-comprehension:

```
def my_string(size):
    return "".join(("y", "n")[x % 2] for x in range(size))
```

Another option:

```
def my_string(size):
    return ("yn" * (size // 2)) + ("y" * (size % 2))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize, but you can use `*` on strings. For example, `"yn" * 2` would return `"ynyn"`.

Comment: I do realize that, but I didn't choose to use it.  I think I'll add another option using it, though.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
def my_string(size):
    if size % 2 == 0:
        return 'yn' * (size / 2)
    else:
        return 'yn' * (size / 2) + 'y'
```

If size is an even number, we print 'yn' `size/2` times.
If size is an odd number, we print 'yn' `size/2` times plus another 'y'.